# Given a continuous $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, show that a point exists in a compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ subject to some rule.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm struggling to see the way out of this problem, it is stated as follows:

> Given a continuous $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. for every point $p\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ we know that $||f(p)|| < \frac{||p||}{2}$ show that a point $q\in K$ exists s.t. $f(q) = \frac{q}{2}$.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem, any push in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Take a point in $K$ and a point not in $K$, and connect them by a continuous curve. Use the intermediate value theorem.